# DevOps: Epics and Features not showing up in Plan (Delivery)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I am trying to create a delivery plan and have added start and target dates to the the epics and the features but they still don't show up in the delivery plan. They only show up if i assign them to an iteration and since epics/features span multiple iterations it doesn't make sense to assign them to an iteration. Any idea how this can be resolved?

Added start and target dates
Assigned epics/features to an iteration

Answer (score 0):

For work items and dependency lines to appear on the plan: **Iteration paths** must be assigned to each work item. Addressed in this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops#prerequisites).

For work items that span one or more iterations, define Start Date and Target Date. The plan displays cards that start and end according to the dates that you set, as shown in the following image. You can also grab the left or right border of a work item and drag it to a new start date or target date. Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops#show-work-that-spans-one-or-more-iterations) for details.

[image]

[image]